# Selected state of UIButton in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton, selected

I have `UIButton` in each cell of `UITableView`. When I touch it, its state is set to selected. But when I scroll table view so the button isn't visible, the state is set to normal. How can I do it that `UIButton` remain selected?

Thank you.

Edit: Here is the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

if (indexPath.row < [messagesArray count]) {

    Zprava *msgObj = [messagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    int width = 0;

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {
        width = 320;
    } else {
        width = 480;
    }

    CGSize boundingSize = CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX);   
    CGSize requiredSize = [msgObj.mmessage sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17] constrainedToSize:boundingSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    UIButton *background = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 25, 300, requiredSize.height + 20)];
    [background setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"balloon.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:15 topCapHeight:15] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [background setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected-balloon.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:15 topCapHeight:15] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [background addTarget:self action:@selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    background.tag = msgObj.msgID;
    [[cell contentView] addSubview:background];
    [background release];

    UILabel *dateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 285, 15)];
    [dateLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
    [dateLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    [dateLabel setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [dateLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [dateLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight];
    [dateLabel setText:msgObj.mdate];
    [dateLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];    
    [dateLabel setOpaque:NO];
    [[cell contentView] addSubview:dateLabel];
    [dateLabel release];

    UILabel *messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 30, 275, requiredSize.height + 5)];
    [messageLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17]];
    [messageLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    [messageLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [messageLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [messageLabel setText:msgObj.mmessage];
    [messageLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; 
    [messageLabel setOpaque:NO];
    [[cell contentView] addSubview:messageLabel];
    [messageLabel release];

}

return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save button states somewhere in your model separately from table view and set buttons state  in `cellForRowAtIndexpath:` method again.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But can you please tell me, how to detect that state of UIButton has been changed?

Comment: button state changes when user taps it, doesn't it? So you should do that in tap handler

Comment: No, I think when the state changed itself from selected to normal.

Comment: Could you post the code for cellForRowAtIndexpath? When you reuse table cell your button state may get reset for some reason, button can't change its state itself